# Disabling informational message highlights in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

If you're getting warnings for some code in Visual Studio and you want to silence them (no highlighting, not appearing in Error List) you can use:

```
#pragma warning disable CODE123
```

Oddly, however, this does nothing to stop it when you're getting "informational" messages for some code, like "Member name can be simplified".

Is there a way to disable these informational messages for a certain segment of code?

Comment: why, visual studio enforces so the standards that microsoft, considers vital, as it doesn't matter if simplify it or not, do it and go on

Comment: [Code-style rule options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/code-style-rule-options) & Co., e.g.,[Code quality rule configuration options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/code-quality-rule-options)